# Flutter Create Design 5 Plus Buttons

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a pretty simple problem/request for code. I am trying to build an app in flutter, and am stuck on one key part of it. Basically, I want there to be 5 plus buttons in a row along the width of the screen. When the user clicks on a plus button, I want it to turn into a text input widget, where an alertbox comes up on the screen and the user can input some text. Then, when the user presses add, it appears on the text input widget. I have no clue how to do this, but I desperately need your help because it's a key feature of the app.

Here is a image of what I am trying to make:
[image]

MORE INFO:

- Starts with 5 + buttons
- User clicks button and the button turns to something like this _______
- While that is happening, an alert box pops up on the screen (I think its called a dialog box)
- User inputs text, and the ______ turns to _e_x_a_m_p_l_e

Thank you so much for your help!!!!!

EDIT: The first underline is what I want the other + buttons to look like when the user clicks on it

Comment: Let me say something, I also started as beginner, we all do. And I also started with questions like this. I will try to help you, cause I did same as you. But you cant ask questions like this: I have this problem, solve it. You have to try it by your self, show the people what you tried and where you cant go any further. Or where you get an error. For example you can show some code of how you tried it for only one button? or to open a Input Dialog with only one Button? Good luck on your way and with your App :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Row, where you show your + Buttons you can do something like this

```
/// here first implement something to check the button is pressed or not
bool firstButton = false;
bool secondButton......
Row(
   children: [
      firstButton ?     
      TextField (  
        decoration: InputDecoration(  
          border: InputBorder.none,  
          labelText: 'Enter Name',  
          hintText: 'Enter Your Name'  
      ),:
    Icon(Icons.add),
    secondButton ? ..............

 /// and so on
    );  
   ]
)
```

You can build and show dilog on press a button like this:

```
onTap: () =>  showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => myInputHandlerWidget( 
    buttonPressed: firstButton // Update this, when user adds a text, the text is not empty and presses ok.
    //here you can add some inputs, for example if you want to add 
    the entered string to a string variable from your main widget.
                         ),)
```